# Linux SWT Browser JavaScript.window.close() method not working

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, browser, swt

I have implemented sample swt browser application, it's working in windows operating system, but the same code I have tested in linux operating system, browser is opening but `window.close()` function is not working in linux. How to fix this issue?

Sample code

```
public class AdvancedBrowser
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setBounds(5, 5, 600, 600);

        browser.addCloseWindowListener(new CloseWindowListener()
        {
            public void close(WindowEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("closing");
                Browser browser = (Browser) event.widget;
                Shell shell = browser.getShell();
                shell.close();
            }
        });

        browser.setText("<a href=\"javascript:window.close();\">Close this Window</a>");
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `window.close()` is not allowed in all browsers. Internet Explorer (which is used on Windows when you use `SWT.NONE`) allows scripts to close browser windows (although it may show a prompt).

Chrome and Firefox (tested on Windows and Linux) won't allow scripts to close the window.

Since you can't really use IE in SWT on Linux, I can't think of a way to make `window.close()` work.

---

**However**, you can call Java code from JavaScript within the SWT `Browser`:

```
private static Browser browser;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setBounds(5, 5, 600, 600);

    browser.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            System.out.println("closing");
            Browser browser = (Browser) event.widget;
            Shell shell = browser.getShell();
            shell.close();
        }
    });

    new CustomFunction(browser, "theJavaFunction");

    browser.setText("<a href=\"javascript:theJavaFunction();\">Close this Window</a>");
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static class CustomFunction extends BrowserFunction
{
    CustomFunction(Browser browser, String name)
    {
        super(browser, name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object function(Object[] arguments)
    {
        System.out.println("theJavaFunction() called from javascript");
        Shell shell = browser.getShell();
        shell.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

There's a nice tutorial by Vogella [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/).